# Is it possible to create an iOS app with Go without Swift or Objective-C?

Tags: ios, go, react-native

I will soon start mobile development on iOS and I would like to know if it possible to create an app with Go along with React Native ​​(for example) without using Swift or Objective-C.

I searched for answers about Quora and Google, but none are precise enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is good question, and I did many research on this, results:

The most promising option in Golang is: [Package app lets you write portable all-Go apps for Android and iOS](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/app)

---

Most applications in Apple’s App Store are written in the Objective-C and Swift programming languages, and developers typically use Xcode to develop their applications ([Four Ways To Build A Mobile Application, Part 1: Native iOS](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/four-ways-to-build-a-mobile-app-part1-native-ios/)).

---

There are some cross-platform options:
- [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)
- [Building HTML5 mobile apps with the Ionic Framework](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/ios/index.html)
- [Xamarin.iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/)
- [Develop iOS applications with RAD Studio](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/ios-development)
- [PhoneGap, build cross-platform apps using HTML, CSS and Javascript](http://phonegap.com/getstarted/)
- [Cordova apps for iOS](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html)
- [Adobe AIR for iOS, built with ActionScript and Flash as iOS apps](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air_for_ios.html)

---

Some relative questions:
[Developing cross platform mobile application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369413/developing-cross-platform-mobile-application)
[How to build a cross platform app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109022/how-to-build-a-cross-platform-app)
[Building Cross Platform app - recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353305/building-cross-platform-app-recommendation)
[React Native v Xamarin Forms - Choosing Cross Platform App Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048820/react-native-v-xamarin-forms-choosing-cross-platform-app-environment)
[List of Delphi language features and version in which they were introduced/deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460037/list-of-delphi-language-features-and-version-in-which-they-were-introduced-depre)

Answer (score 3):

There are alternatives to native iOS apps without Swift or Obj-c, such as HTML5, Xamarin (C#), PhoneGap, Cordova, etc. but these alternatives have sacrifices.

Most of your extra coding time would be invested in workarounds to make these alternative technologies work. If you want your app to perform better than a web app, then you should use Obj-C or Swift.

Answer (score 1):

You can build basic (and more with packages) iOS/Android apps using react-native. It is a great tool to build iOS apps using js. There are loads of modules and community support (https://js.coach/) to help you build out of the basics. I've been building apps on react-native and the result is on par with native apps. There is a small learning curve in react-native but it is definitely worth it